# FLAR inverted marker

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, augmented-reality, flartoolkit

Does someone knows where can I find some information how to detect a "white" marker on a black page?

Comment: What is the object type for the marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for this problem, using FLARManager. http://words.transmote.com/wp/flarmanager/flarmanager-documentation/#flarManagerSettings_inverted
Hope it helps someone else in future.